# Add margin to tag button/increase padding between lines

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, badges

For example, on [this badge page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) you can see that there is no margin between lines:

> [image]

'cause tag button doesn't have margin:

```
.badges-page .single-badge-table .single-badge-wrapper .single-badge-badge a, .badges-page .single-badge-table .single-badge-wrapper .single-badge-title a {
    margin: 0;
}
```

If you disable this rule, it will look fine:

> [image]

Can you do something with it?